# Export/Copy + Paste a plot from Mathematica Trial Version to TeX editor

Tags: plotting, export, warning-messages

I wish to get a view plots from Mathematica trial version into a TeX editor, but cannot seem to do it (unless I print the screen and crop the image which leads to bad quality). Is there a way in which I can?

I have tried saving the plot as an image file and copying the LaTeX code across but neither will allow me to do so.

I should also note that I have a legend for the graph, which seems to be slightly separated... I'd ideally like both to be copied across.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The trial version does not support export operations, so this is not possible with the trial.